# MacOSX Multicast storm on my LAN

Tags: mac-osx, osx-snow-leopard

In my LAN of around 100 Macs, we have serious problems in the network. For some reason unknown to me, Macs flood the network with this traffic (sniffer sample),

```
08:11:12.757245 IP 224.0.0.1 > 192.168.1.101: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 52
08:11:12.758818 IP 224.0.0.1 > 192.168.1.101: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 52
08:11:12.761885 IP 224.0.0.1 > 192.168.1.101: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 52
08:11:12.763429 IP 224.0.0.1 > 192.168.1.101: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 52
08:11:12.768031 IP 224.0.0.1 > 192.168.1.101: ICMP time exceeded in-transit, length 52
```

The `192.168.1.101` IP is the 'evil' Mac computer.

Only when turning off or unplug the net, the Mac stop the storm.

My network is paralyzed after this, the only temporary solution was to apply this patch, http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3789, but the problem persists in a few times.

I can do anything?

Answer (score 1):

Fire up netstat on the bad machine and find out what process has open connections to the multicast address.

Comment: OK, i'll try in this moment

Comment: Yes, the process is mDNSResponder

Comment: OK - so why does the problem recur after you add "-NoMulticastAdvertisements" ?  Does something remove that string?